# Authentication exception spring ldap-server and ldaptemplate

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, security, active-directory

First of all, excuse my English.

I've been trying to find a solution for 3 days, but I can not find it.

I am trying to connect to AD LDAP to perform user searches that will be registered in an app.

Authentication to the application is via Spring-Security-CAS and is correct.

The problem I have is that windows works perfectly, but when deploying the application in linux gives authentication error.
I tried to escape the special characters according to the documentation, but it does not matter, the error remains the same.

I just want to connect to LDAP to make user queries about it.

The configuration I use is the Spring-Ldap standard.

```
    <security:ldap-server id="contextSource"
    url="${pso.ldap.url}"
    manager-dn="${pso.ldap.userDn}"
    manager-password="${pso.ldap.password}"
    root="${ldap.auth.search.ldap}"/>


<ldap:ldap-template id="ldapTemplate" 
    context-source-ref="contextSource"
    ignore-partial-result="true"/>
```

Te userDn has this value

```
CN=Usuario (Autenticación LDAP),OU=xxxx8,OU=XXXXXX XXXXX,DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM
```

I would appreciate a help of what is possible error or what additional configuration is missing.

```
        try {

        logger.info("MOSTRAR PARAMETROS CONEXION CONTEXTSOURCE....");
        //CATCH WHEN TRY TO WRITE THIS IN ORDER TO VIEW DATA TO TEST.
        //BUT IF COMMENT THIS LINE THEN THE ERROR IS ON search method
        logger.info("PARAMETERS CNX: " + ldapTemplate.getContextSource().getReadOnlyContext().getEnvironment().toString());

        String resultKeySearch = ASTERISK.concat(keySearch).concat(ASTERISK);

        query = query().base(LDAP_BASE)
                .attributes("cn", "userPrincipalName", "sAMAccountName", "displayName")
                .where("objectclass").is("person").and("objectclass").is("user")
                .and(query().where("cn")
                        .like(resultKeySearch)
                        .or("userPrincipalName").like(resultKeySearch)
                        .or("sAMAccountName").like(resultKeySearch)
                        .or("displayName").like(resultKeySearch)
                        );

        persons = ldapTemplate.search(query, new PersonAttributesMapper());

    } catch (org.springframework.ldap.NamingException e) {
        logger.catching(e);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        logger.catching(e);
    }
```

The error it generates is the same

> 2017-03-20 10:56:56,794 ERROR [com.psoplaneta.auth.web.api.rest.exceptions.handler.CustomRestExceptionHandler] (default task-17) error: org.springframewor                k.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903AA, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 525, v1772]; nested ex                ception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903AA, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 525,                 v1772]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi,I solved my problem connecting with user xxxx@domain.com